# Vue change color of input field when clicked delete button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am really new to vue js and I am trying to change the input field color when user click on the `trash-fill button`. Currently when I upload a character on input field it changes the color to green.

Is there a way to change input field color from green to white when the user click on `<b-icon icon="trash-fill" font-scale="1.5" @click="deleteRfidBeforeReload($event, index, 10)"></b-icon>` ?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(listings, index) in list10" :key="index">
   <b-row>
     <b-col sm="6">
       <b-form-input id="input-live" :value="listings.first_name" disabled></b-form-input>
     </b-col>
     <b-col sm="4">
       <b-form-input v-model="listings.rfidState1" ref="todos" v-on:input="posttorfidapi($event, 10, index)" 
:style="listings.rfidState1 ? { 'background-color': '#33FF90', color:'#33FF90' } : null"></b-form-input>
     </b-col>
      <b-col sm="2">
        <b-icon icon="trash-fill" font-scale="1.5" @click="deleteRfidBeforeReload($event, index, 10)"></b-icon>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list10: [
      { first_name: "mission1", id: "1", rfidState1:""},
      { first_name: "mission2", id: "2", rfidState1:""},
      { first_name: "mission3", id: "3", rfidState1:""},
      { first_name: "mission4", id: "4", rfidState1:""}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    posttorfidapi(event, col, index){
        if(event.length > 3){
        console.log("CHANGE INPUT FIELD COLOR TO GREEN");
      }
    },
    deleteRfidBeforeReload($event, index, col){
        console.log(index);
      console.log("CHANGE THE PARTICULAR INPUT FIELD TO WHITE AGAIN");
    }
  }
})
```

**My code on JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/7qsnvftm/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using the ternary operator. You could introduce a new property in your objects in your array, which we would toggle `true` or `false`, for example `whiteBackground`, toggle it to `true` when button is clicked and back to `false`, when input changes (I assume this is what you want). Then you can nest this as a further ternary operator to your already existing one. So I suggest the following:

```
  list10: [
    {
      first_name: "mission1",
      id: "1",
      rfidState1: "",
      whiteBackground: false
    },
    //...
  ]
```

Methods:

```
posttorfidapi(event, col, index) {
    this.list10[index].whiteBackground = false;
    console.log("CHANGE INPUT FIELD COLOR TO GREEN");
  }
},
deleteRfidBeforeReload($event, index, col) {
  this.list10[index].whiteBackground = true;
  console.log("CHANGE THE PARTICULAR INPUT FIELD TO WHITE AGAIN");
}
```

And the ternary condition:

```
:style="listings.rfidState1 ? listings.whiteBackground ? '' : 
   { 'background-color': '#33FF90', color:'#33FF90' }  : ''"
```

**[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-cache-210c1?file=/App.vue)**

BTW, your fiddle does not work...

Comment: that logic fixed it. Thank You. My fiddle does not work as bootstrap vue was imported but i did not know how to call it on JSFIDDLE.

Comment: OK, glad I could help! Well, good was that the fiddle was present, so we could see all the code if necessary  :)